# Rational ClearQuest Http request to find defects that have been updated since a specific time?

Tags: rest, http, clearquest

I am trying to use ClearQuest OSLC CM REST API to write an http request to accomplish the following. I want to get a list (in the XML format) of ClearQuest defects that have been updated since a specified time.

So far I have been able to get a list of all defects from a particular defect family that I'm interested in with the following request (I'm using a sample base URL here):

```
http://localhost:8080/oslc/cqrest/repo/7.0.0/db/SAMPL/record/?oslc_cm.query=Found_in_Product_Family="MyDefectFamily"&rcm.type=Defect
```

I also was able to put together an http request that returned a complete timestamp history for a single defect like so:

```
http://localhost:8080/oslc/cqrest/repo/7.0.0/db/SAMPL/record/16777241-38577895?oslc_cm.properties=id,dbid,history{action_timestamp}
```

I can show sample xml response for both of those requests if anyone thinks it can be helpful here.

I can't seem to figure out how to write a request that will return a list of defects (id, dbid, timestamp) that contain a timestamp later than say 01/01/2014 00:00:00. Or at least a request that would return all defects where each defect entry would contain the last timestamp in it's history. I think I can get a list of all defects with all timestamps for each defect but I would like just the last timestamp. Taking the last node in the timestamp history doesn't work. Timestamp history doesn't seem to be ordered. Some sort of max function seems to be necessary for such a request.

Can anyone point me in the right direction or tell if what I want is impossible with ClearQuest OSLC CM REST API?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use in VB.NET:

```
Dim asOfValue = asOf.ToString("'""'yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'Z""^^xsd:dateTime'")
Dim upToValue = upTo.ToString("'""'yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'Z""^^xsd:dateTime'")
Dim where = "cq:history{cq:action_timestamp>=" & asOfValue & " and cq:action_timestamp<=" & upToValue & "}"

Const prefix = "cq=<http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/rational/clearquest/1.0/>"
uri.Query = String.Format("oslc.orderBy=dcterms:identifier&oslc.where={0}&oslc.select={1}&oslc.prefix={2}", where, select, prefix)
```

Comment: Did you have any luck with this or do you need more information?